# Which of the following series converge? (With Legendre-Polynomials)

Tags: sequences-and-series, legendre-polynomials

These should be quick tasks:
We know that the Legendre Polynomials satisfy $\int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x)P_{n}(x)dx= \delta_{mn}\frac{2}{2n+1}$

Which of the following series converge ( $ \forall x \in [-1,1]$ )? 
i) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nP_n(x)$ 
ii) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 2^{-n} P_n(x)$ 
iii) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_{n^2}(x)$ 
iv) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}P_n(x) $

I tried with the Parseval Identity $||f||^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |(P_n,f)|^2$ but I didn't find a useful $f$ to plug in and somehow get any of the sums on the right hand side.

I think the 2nd sum does converge since we have exponential decrease and $P_n$ is a polynomial. Since iv) grows slower than i) I assume iv) converges and i) doesn't, but I don't have any real mathematical argument for that.

Comment: What is the range for $x$ in the sums?

Comment: @Gary $ \forall x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: For the endpoints you can use $P_n(1)=1$ and $P_n(-1)=(-1)^n$. Otherwise, use the asymptotics $$
P_n (\cos \alpha ) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{{\pi n\sin \alpha }}} \cos \left( {\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\alpha  - \frac{\pi }{4}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(n^{ - 3/2} )
$$ ($0 < \alpha  < \pi$) and the Dirichlet test with the fact that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {\cos \left( {\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\alpha  - \frac{\pi }{4}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{2} - \cos \left( {(N + 1)\alpha  + \frac{\pi }{4}} \right)} \right)\csc \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right).
$$